# is installing rails and vb .net on same machine safe?

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been learning some VB .NET and jusr wanted to know if installing rails on the same machine is ok, that no conflicts will occur? Perhaps a stupid question but one i think might be worth asking before i do install rails.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They shouldn't interfere because those frameworks are fundamentally distinct. I would recommend that you install Rails/Ruby with [RVM](https://rvm.io), its very easy and comes in handy later. Also I would strongly suggest not to develop Rails on Windows because some things don't work on it as they do under Unixes.

Comment: Ahh i didnt realize this. I'm currently using windows... perhaps i should try get my old mac working.

Comment: Yeah that works much better, but with Ruby Performance is also a concern. If your mac is very old you'll have to wait alot. If I were you I would try it on windows and if you run into troubles change to mac. Ruby + Rails is very easy to install with RVM and also very easy to deinstall (rvm implode, and youre done).

Comment: Thanks i will give this a try, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is. I have installed on my testing machine.

PS: I will suggest to install ubuntu in dual boot or in virtual box and then install try out rails on ubuntu. As its so easy to configure rails/gems/plugins on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

There should be no conflicts all the way down to which port the server is listening to. If they both, for example, try to take incoming port 8080 to serve pages over, then you're going to have the second one fail, as the port is in use. This is a fairly obvious error, and easy to configure. The technologies themselves are totally separate and shouldn't stomp on each other.